# Adicionar variável javascript na classe CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu preciso inserir nessa seguinte classe CSS:

```
    .bola {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

a variável `var corBola = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)`
que gera um valor hexadecimal de cor aleatório, como eu posso fazer a inserção para mudar a cor e inserir o atributo de background-color usando essa variável aleatória?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bola").style.backgroundColor = corBola;
```

jQuery:

```
$('.bola').css({'background-color': corBola});
```